# Problem display a page on Android and IOS

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, xamarin

The first page after login displays nothing. I have a page which allows you to display the published data (name, description, image) by retrieving them from the database, on Windows machine it works but on IOS it displays but I can't do anything about it (the buttons don't work) and on Android it doesn't even display.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:root="clr-namespace:Orbis.Mobile"
             x:Class="Orbis.Mobile.ActivitiePage">
    
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <root:BytesToImageConverter x:Key="ToImage" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <BoxView x:Name="Box" BackgroundColor="White" />
                <!--<SearchBar 
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="300"/>-->
                <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Source="ic_add.png" x:Name="Plus" Clicked="Plus_Clicked"
                     VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" HeightRequest="35" Aspect="AspectFit" />

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="4">
                    <RefreshView Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"                SelectionMode="None">
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackLayout Padding="10" >

                                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnItemTapped" />
                                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ToImage}}" 
                                                   HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="70"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                                                   Style="{DynamicResource ListItetextStyle}" FontSize="16" 
                                                   TextColor="Black"/>
                                            <Button Text="Update" HorizontalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="DarkOrange" Margin="0,20,0,0" TextColor="White"
                                                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:ActivitieViewModel}}, Path=OnEditCommand}"
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" IsVisible="{Binding IsUpdated}"></Button>
                                            <Button Text="Delete" HorizontalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="0,20,0,0" TextColor="White" Clicked="Delete_Clicked"    
                                                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:ActivitieViewModel}}, Path=DeleteItemCommand}"
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" IsVisible="{Binding IsUpdated}"></Button>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    This code was generated by a tool.
    It was generated from C:\Users\codyj\Downloads\Orbis-main (1) (2)\Orbis-main\Orbis.Mobile\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml
    Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    the contents are regenerated.
    -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" package="com.companyname.orbis.mobile" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/orbisimage" android:supportsRtl="true" android:name="..." android:label="Orbis.Mobile" android:debuggable="true" android:extractNativeLibs="true">
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="...">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:host="auth" />
                <data android:scheme="..." />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="density|orientation|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|screenSize|uiMode" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Maui.SplashTheme" android:name="..." android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true" android:name="...f.WebAuthenticatorIntermediateActivity" />
        <!--<provider android:authorities="com.companyname.orbis.mobile.fileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="microsoft.maui.essentials.fileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/microsoft_maui_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths" />
        </provider>-->
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64e53d2f592022988e.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver" />
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true" android:name="...y" />
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Battery Broadcast Receiver" android:name="....BatteryBroadcastReceiver" />
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Energy Saver Broadcast Receiver" android:name="...f2.EnergySaverBroadcastReceiver" />
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="...BrowserTabActivity" />
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="microsoft.identity.client.AuthenticationActivity" />
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true" android:name="....AuthenticationAgentActivity" />
        <service android:name="...KeepAliveService" />
        <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="..." android:authorities="com.companyname.orbis.mobile.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    </application>
    <!--suppress UsesMinSdkAttributes-->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
</manifest>
```

```
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Data.Common.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.orbis.mobile/files/.__override__/System.Data.Common.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.orbis.mobile/files/.__override__/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly [External]
[me.orbis.mobile] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 486(107KB) AllocSpace objects, 93(11MB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4327KB/8655KB, paused 631us,220us total 33.259ms
[me.orbis.mobile] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3(16KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 4327KB/8655KB, paused 584us,106us total 23.953ms
[me.orbis.mobile] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3(16KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 4327KB/8655KB, paused 546us,107us total 20.148ms
[Choreographer] Skipped 99 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[me.orbis.mobile] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3192(155KB) AllocSpace objects, 12(432KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4332KB/8664KB, paused 562us,170us total 18.262ms
[me.orbis.mobile] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 168(19KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 4328KB/8656KB, paused 502us,113us total 16.358ms
[Choreographer] Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=3487.21ms min=11.75ms max=26861.14ms count=8
```

```
namespace Orbis.Mobile.ViewModels;

[QueryProperty(nameof(ItemId), nameof(ItemId))]
public class ActivitieViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string itemId;
    private string text;
    private string description;
    private string image;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
    public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; }
    public Command AddItemCommand { get; }
    public Command<Item> ItemTapped { get; }
    public Command OnEditCommand { get; }
    public Command<Item> DeleteItemCommand { get; }

    public ActivitieViewModel()
    {

        Title = "Browse";
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());

        ItemTapped = new Command<Item>(OnItemSelected);

        AddItemCommand = new Command(OnAddItem);
        OnEditCommand = new Command(OnEditItem);
        DeleteItemCommand = new Command<Item>(OnDeleteItem);
    }

    async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            Items.Clear();
            var items = await GetItemsAsync(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsUpdated { get; set; }

    public string Text
    {
        get => text;
        set => SetProperty(ref text, value);
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get => description;
        set => SetProperty(ref description, value);
    }

    public string Image
    {
        get => image;
        set => SetProperty(ref image, value);
    }

    public string ItemId
    {
        get
        {
            return itemId;
        }
        set
        {
            itemId = value;
            LoadItemId(value);
        }
    }

    public async void LoadItemId(string itemId)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = await DataStore.GetItemAsync(itemId);
            Id = item.Id;
            Text = item.Text;
            Description = item.Description;
            UserId = item.UserId;
            IsUpdated = item.IsUpdated;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to Load Item");
        }
    }

    private async void OnEditItem(object obj)
    {
        var selectedItem = (Item)obj;

        await AppShell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(UpdateActivitiePage)}",
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["ActivitieItem"] = selectedItem,
            });
    }

    private async void OnDeleteItem(Item item)
    {
        try
        {
            Items.Remove(item);

            await DeleteItemAsync(item.Id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    private async void OnAddItem(object obj)
    {

    }

    async void OnItemSelected(Item item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
    {
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpclient.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppSettings.UrlApi);

            string oauthToken = await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(AppSettings.AuthToken);
            httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", oauthToken);
            var requestUri = "/api/v1/Activities/all";

            var response = await httpclient.GetAsync(requestUri);

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ActivitiesModel>>(content);
                int loginUserId = Convert.ToInt32(value: await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(AppSettings.UserId));

                foreach (var d in data)
                {
                    var item = new Item
                    {
                        Id = d.Id.ToString(),
                        Text = d.Name,
                        Description = d.Description,
                        Image = d.Images?.Blob ?? string.Empty,
                        UserId = d.UserId,
                        IsUpdated = loginUserId == d.UserId,
                        GroupId = d.Group_id,
                    };

                    Items.Add(item);
                }
            }

        };

        return await Task.FromResult(Items);
    }

    private async Task DeleteItemAsync(string itemId)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppSettings.UrlApi);

            string oauthToken = await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(AppSettings.AuthToken);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", oauthToken);
            var requestUri = $"/api/v1/Activities/{itemId}";

            var response = await httpClient.DeleteAsync(requestUri);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Item deleted successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to delete item");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to debug, the information comes directly from the database, I have a status 200 but it is probably the display that is the problem

[image: Image of screen]

Comment: Is there any log about this problem?

Comment: Could you please post the code of your ViewModel of this page?

Comment: Yes I will add right now

Comment: Based on the code you shared, I created a demo and added some fake data for Items, and the data could display normally. Can you load data correctly for `Items` in `ActivitieViewModel.cs` ? And one thing I don't quite understand is why you set the row of the outer `StackLayout` of `RefreshView` to `4`. Since the maximum number of rows is 4, the number of rows we can use is from `0` to `3`.

Comment: And at beginning, there is no initial data to display.  We need to slide down the area occupied by the `RefreshView` to trigger the `LoadItemsCommand` to load the data.

Comment: There are many elements that can cause problems, I'll let you look at them or test them on github: https://github.com/Essama-Official/Orbis

Comment: We don't need such detailed code, for the copyright of your code, please remove the link of your code. You can just [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And meanwhile please post the steps of reproducing your problem.

Comment: I did the best I could : https://github.com/Essama-Official/OrbisDemoTest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255198/discussion-between-jessie-zhang-msft-and-chris-curt).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you shared, I could reproduce this problem.

And I found that If I set a height for the outer `StackLayout` of the `RefreshView`, the `Items` could display normally.

You can refer to the following code:

```
 <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" HeightRequest="600" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
     <RefreshView Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

**Update:**

> For Android it's good it works, but IOS it's buggy, the application
> even crashes, the page works at first, but after that I can't scroll
> anymore and the buttons don't work anymore

Since there is no any other view on top of `RefreshView`, so you can try to define two rows for the Grid, and set the row of the outer `StackLayout` of `RefreshView` to `1`.

And the two buttons(`Update` and `Delete`) on the item of the List could also been triggered on my side.

Please refer to the following code:

```
   <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="Green" > 
       <Grid>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="*" />
           <!--<RowDefinition Height="*" />
               <RowDefinition Height="*" />-->
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <BoxView x:Name="Box" BackgroundColor="Pink"  />
           <!--<SearchBar 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               WidthRequest="300"/>-->

           <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Yellow" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="500">
               <RefreshView Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
                   <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"                SelectionMode="None">
                       <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                               <StackLayout Padding="2" >

                                   <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                       <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnItemTapped" />
                                   </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                                   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Pink">
                                       <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ToImage}}"  BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue"
                                              HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="70"/>
                                       <Label Text="{Binding Text}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                              Style="{DynamicResource ListItetextStyle}" FontSize="16" 
                                              TextColor="Black"/>
                                       <Button Text="Update" HorizontalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="DarkOrange" Margin="0,20,0,0" TextColor="White"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:ActivitieViewModel}}, Path=OnEditCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" IsVisible="{Binding IsUpdated}"></Button>
                                        <Button Text="Delete" HorizontalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="0,20,0,0" TextColor="White" Clicked="Delete_Clicked"    
                                        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:ActivitieViewModel}}, Path=DeleteItemCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" IsVisible="{Binding IsUpdated}"></Button>   
                                   </StackLayout>

                               </StackLayout>
                           </DataTemplate>
                       </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                   </CollectionView>
               </RefreshView>
           </StackLayout>
       </Grid>
   </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Great it works, but there is just a lot of space between the AppShell buttons and the page, I tried to reduce with Margin=0 or Margin = "0, 0, 0, 20" but there is still space, do you have any idea why?

Comment: You can try to reduce the value of  `<StackLayout Padding="10" >` for the inner `DataTemplate` of the `CollectionView` .  For example: `<StackLayout Padding="2" >` .

Comment: For Android it's good it works, but IOS it's buggy, the application even crashes, the page works at first, but after that I can't scroll anymore and the buttons don't work anymore

Comment: Could you please post the full error log on iOS?

Comment: I can test only on Testflight

Comment: I reduced the green space by doing HeightRequest="300", however the data displayed does not take up all the space on the page, even in VerticaloOptions=FillandExpand, nothing works, there is just a large empty space

Comment: Could you please post the screenshot of your result ?

Comment: Sure, It's done

Comment: Have you set the  `Padding` of  the inner `StackLayout`  of the `<DataTemplate>` to a smaller value?  For example: 
                `<DataTemplate> <StackLayout Padding="2" >`